# Firebug syntax error

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd"
      xml:lang="en">
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
var a = 4;
```

Firebug:

```
syntax error
var a = 4;
 ^
```

Comment: Worked fine for me (FF 3.5.5, FB 1.4.5). Maybe move the script part to the head? Other plug-ins conflicting?

Comment: I am not getting any script error from your code.

Comment: That's the entire source. Be sure Firebug is active for scripts before refreshing and checking the error console.

Comment: Done and done. No errors logged.

Comment: What OS are you using? (I'm using Win 7.)

Comment: I think powtac and Soufiane Hassou is on to something. I don´t see any content-type definition in your file and if you test your file over the file-protocol the UA can only guess what encoding to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `language="javascript"` it is not XHTML valid!

Add also a character encoding meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: The language="javascript" was doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Check the validator from W3C.

Answer (score 2):

Your file probably has some hidden character which is causing the problem. Create a new file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that kind of error show up when the DTD is incorrect, or the page doesn't quite validate with that DTD. It's totally unintuitive, but try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some encoding problem? UTF with BOM? Create a new plain txt file and rename it to test.js and write(!) in the code again.